# Calculating with dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

i have written this code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ5Zm.png)

```
    meses = Operaciones_LC.groupby([Operaciones_LC.Time.dt.year, Operaciones_LC.Time.dt.month])
    resultados = []
    contador = 0
    ultima_tupla = None
    year = None
    month = None
    
    for grupo, datos in meses:
        
       year, month =     grupo
       profit      =     datos[datos['Operacion'] > 0]['Operacion'].sum()
       loss        = abs(datos[datos['Operacion'] < 0]['Operacion'].sum())
       
       if loss == 0:
           profit_factor = 99
       else:
           profit_factor = profit / loss
           
       resultados.append((year, month, profit_factor))

       if profit_factor < 1:
        contador += 1
       else:
        contador = 0
    
       if contador == 6:
        ultima_tupla = year,month       
        ultima_tupla_vector = np.array(ultima_tupla)
        
        year, month = grupo
        meses_nuevo = Nuevo_DataFrame(DataFrame_ASK, DataFrame_BID, ultima_tupla_vector, N, k, k_corto)
        meses = meses_nuevo.groupby([meses_nuevo.Time.dt.year , meses_nuevo.Time.dt.month])
        contador=0
```

I am working with the dataframe "meses", which I group in months and years, and once the condition that "profit factor for six months < 1" occurs, I calculate a new dataframe, and I would like the loop to run at from that month and year with the new dataframe "meses" but continue with the old one,

would anyone know why?

Thanks in advance

I want a list named "resultados" with the year, month and profit factor of each month and year.

Comment: When the line `for grupo, datos in meses:` is reached initially, `meses` is evaluated and the for-loop iterates over this object even if `meses` refers to another object later.

Comment: Possible solution can be to wrap the for-loop in another loop (while-loop) and to `break` from the inner loop after `meses` was changed so that by the outer loop the inner for-loop starts again with another `meses`.

Comment: What would be in that case the argument in the while-loop?

Comment: Your code could e. g. set `meses` to `None` if it detects that no more data is available so a `while meses is not None` should work then.